# Use of the word "when."

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In the following sentence, "People eat garlic when it is raw or cooked." is "when it is raw or cooked." an adverbial clause or an adjective clause?  The way I see it, this clause can either talk about garlic or eating.  Adverbs answer "how" questions and "when" can answer "how."

Other examples that fit this model:

"Vampires leave their coffin when it's dark."
"When it's hot, I drink cold beers."
"You use a pen when you are certain."
"I get a cough when it's cold."

Is "when" a word that can introduce two interpretations of a sentence, a sort of "wavicle" (to borrow from the world of quantum mechanics)?

Comment: *Let's have dinner when it is ready*. Is this dependent clause adjective?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the clause  "when it is raw or cooked."  is used as an adjectival as it modifies the noun garlic ( The status of garlic is either raw or cooked , it doesn't modify the action of eating

Comment: I tend to disagree. The fact that the clause is introduced by *when* suggests to me it is adverbial, since it is qualifying the verb *eat*. However if I said *People eat garlic which is either raw or cooked* - it becomes adjectival since it describes *garlic* rather than *eat*. I may be wrong - I am a native speaker and have never been required to distinguish the adverbial fro the adjectival. It just comes naturally.